# How to print multiple functions on one line of code without any unnecessary characters

Tags: python

I want to print multiple functions on one line of code in Python. I am currently using the method in which you put a comma after the print statement

```
print("Hello, my name is " + introName + " and I have a " +outroName+.",)
```

but it prints like this

```
('Hello, my name is Arthur\n and I have a secret.',)
```

How do I get rid of the `\n` `()` , and `'`?

Comment: It's printing like that because you've put your string into a tuple with a single item, which can be defined like `(item1,)`. You simply have to remove the comma at the end, so it looks like `print("Hello, my name is " + introName + " and I have a " +outroName+.")`.

Comment: The answer varies according to what version of Python you are using. Are you using Python2 or Python3? From your description, it appears that you are using Python2.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the value `introName` contains `\n` at the end, you can use `strip()` to remove that.

```
introName.strip('\n')
```

Your line should be:

```
print("Hello, my name is " + introName.strip('\n') + " and I have a " + outroName.strip('\n'))
```

The better is using [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) like this:

```
s = "Hello, my name is {} and I have a {}".format(introName.strip('\n'), outroName.strip('\n'))
print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> introName = 'Arthur\n'
>>> outroName = 'secret'
>>>
>>> s = "Hello, my name is {} and I have a {}".format(introName.strip('\n'), outroName.strip('\n'))
>>> s
'Hello, my name is Arthur and I have a secret'
```